# MongoDB search feed based on if I'm following users

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How could I display to my logged in user a list of posts from people they are following?

I have a post schema (cut down for simplicity):

```
const postSchema = {
    userId: String,
    description: String,
    timestamp: Date,
    longitude: Number,
    latitude: Number,
}
```

And my follower schema (cut down also):

```
const followerSchema = {
    userId: String, // person who click follow on a user
    followingId: String, // the account they were viewing
    timestamp: Date
}
```

How can I find the lastest posts where `post.user` is equal to `follower.followingId` (assuming that `follower.userId` is equal to my logged in user as well)?.

---

**Attempts so far:**

1. I've spent a couple of hours on this and I can pull the results for just posts and then filter them down in Node.js, but this isn't efficient on a mass scale.
2. Here is a lookup query *that isn't working*:

```
const posts = await Post.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
            {
                from: "follower",
                localField: "userId",
                foreignField: "followingId",
                as: "relationship"
            }
    },
    { "$match": { "relationship.userId": req.userId } }
]);

res.send({posts});
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

3. It may be a better solution for me to:

   - Load all users that I follower, and get their IDs
   - Load all posts where `userId` equals any of the userIds in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
const followings = await Follower.find({ userId: req.userId });
const followingIds = followings.map(f => f.followingId);
const posts = await Post.find({ userId: { $in: followingIds } });
```

BTW, using `aggregate` query is a better solution. Try changing this:

```
    $lookup:
        {
            from: "follower",
            localField: "userId",
            foreignField: "following",
            as: "relationship"
        }
```

to:

```
    $lookup:
        {
            from: "followers",
            localField: "userId",
            foreignField: "followingId",
            as: "relationship"
        }
```

Comment: As I said to Sylvain, followingId is following in my code. I just named it followingId in this example to make it clearer. I've updated my question. However, the issue still stands

Comment: You noticed that I used **plural form** (actual DB collection name) in `from` field, right?

Comment: Ah! I did not notice that. I will give that a try. Thank you

Comment: Perfect thank you! I got it working by adding plural form `from: "followers"` and by updating match to load `relationship.0.userId` rather than `relationship.userId`.

Comment: Also @technophyle you legend. You wrote out my attempt 3 and it works perfectly as well. In terms of performance. $lookup solution takes 55ms-60ms. whereas the load users then posts solution takes 29ms-32ms. Wonder which option is better on a bigger scale?

Comment: I think the aggregate is the better solution, though I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the foreignField should be ”followingId”.

Comment: Sorry yes, `followingId` is `following` in my code. I just named it `followingId` in this example to make it clearer. I've updated my question. However, the issue still stands.

Comment: userId and followingId are string type. Have you tried to use ObjectId instead?

Answer (score 0):

From technophyle's answer, I updated `from: "follower"` to be `from: "followers"`.

I also needed to access the first value of the array in the $match rather than the root (needed to add `0`).

`{ "$match": { "relationship.0.userId": req.userId} }`

```
const posts = await Post.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
            {
                from: "followers",
                localField: "userId",
                foreignField: "following",
                as: "relationship"
            }
    },
    { "$match": { "relationship.0.userId": req.userId} }
]);

res.send({posts});
```